# Why does my resistor start smoking when current runs through my circuit?

Tags: resistors, electromagnetic, troubleshooting

This is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxFDU3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, when I wire it up, R2 starts smoking - why does this happen?

[Edited to remove incorrect wire]

Comment: What is the power handling capability (wattage) of the resistor?

Comment: What power is the resistor rated to? You have over 0.5Amp running through a 10 Ohm resistor. That's more than 2.5W.

Comment: Your MOSFET has no effect - you've shorted its drain to source, and as a result your electromagnet will always be switched on.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen That'll be it! Their wattage is 0.25 watts. I need to get hold of some higher wattage resistors then. Thanks!

Comment: @brhans MOSFET's working fine. The middle terminal on the schematic is the gate.

Comment: Not if you have connected it as shown in the schematic. You can remove the MOSFET as drawn now and the circuit would function identically.

Comment: @OrlandoAlexander - I didn't write anything about the gate. It's the *drain* and *source* which you've drawn as shorted together by the wire below your "Power Adapter".

Comment: @brhans Oh! That's my bad - I didn't mean to put that connection in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

P = I<sup>2</sup> · R is dissipated in R2, about 3.4 W, so you need a resistor that can handle that power to keep the smoke in. It will still get hot.

You may want to consider using a 6 V power supply for the electromagnet; it would be less wasteful.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you didn't connect the FET the right way (or your schematic doesn't match what you actually built); as it is shown, with drain shorted to source, it doesn't do anything, and the Pi can't turn the electromagnet off.

Also, the [IRF530](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/irf530.pdf) isn't a very good choice for using with 3.3 V logic; see Fig. 3 (transfer characteristics) in the datasheet.

Comment: The link to the IRF530 does not work. Use this: https://www.vishay.com/docs/91020/sihf530s.pdf. Yes, minimum useful gate voltage is 4.5 volts.

Answer (score 3):

As commenters have pointed out, your circuit shows both the drain and source of the FET are tied to ground so the FET will not be switching the loads on and off as I think you intend to with this circuit.  You need to remove the connection between the anode of your flyback diode and the power supply ground.

As others have also noted, you are putting 0.5A of current through your R2 resistor. If you are breadboarding this circuit with common 1/4W thru hole resistors you are exceeding the power rating of the device by more than a factor of 10. (As drawn, P = I*I*R = 3.6W) If you don't have a resistor capable of handling the power dissipation you can use multiple in parallel, though be sure to calculate the equivalent parallel resistance correctly to maintain the desired current.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, it is just to help you see the problem in the schematic:

[image]

This connection is shorting your mosfet.

Comment: +1 Also, electromagnet cannot be controlled by mcu

Comment: @Sanmvegsaini Why is this the case? It is an energy to release electromagnet by the way.